# Showing that the partial sums of this alternating series with factorials do not vanish before limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I am trying to prove (or disprove) the non-vanishing of the finite summation
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{2k+1}{\sqrt{(n - k)!(n+1+k)!}} \neq 0 \quad \forall n < \infty.$$

Alternatively, that the finite partial sums in the infinite series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{2k+1}{\sqrt{(n - k)!(n+1+k)!}} = 0$$
are not zero.  i.e. they do not miraculously cancel out before they reach infinity.

I strongly suspect the above to be true.

**Attempts**

(note this is not my area of expertise).

Here is a [numerical plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFjqE.png) of the partial sums up to $n=15$.  It appears to be an absolutely convergent series, with even $n$ being positive-definite and odd $n$ being negative-definite.  Not sure how to prove this in general.

Given a fixed $n$, I was hoping the absolute value of each term $a_k = \frac{2k+1}{\sqrt{(n - k)!(n+1+k)!}}$in $S_n$ would be monotonically decreasing, showing for example that an even $n$ would  always be a bit more positive than negative.  But a numerical plot shows this is not the case: [coefficient for n=15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3G0G.png).  I still tried to see if anything can be gained by somehow identifying when in k the peak occurs, maybe to split the sum into before and after.

I have calculated that
$$ a_{k+1} = \sigma_k a_k , \qquad \, \sigma_k = \sqrt{\frac{n-k}{n+k+2}} \Big(\frac{2k+3}{2k+1}\Big).$$
And so the summation can be re-expressed as
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \Big[ \prod_{j=0}^k \sigma_j \Big]a_0, \qquad a_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n! (n+1)!}} .$$

The product can be calculated as
$$ \prod_{j=0}^k \sigma_j = \frac{a_k}{a_0} = \sqrt{\frac{k!(n+1)!}{(n-k)!(n+1+k)!}} = \sqrt{\frac{{}_nP_k}{{}_{n+1+k}P_k}} $$

Now I guess I would take the derivative of this with respect to $k$ (using the Gamma function) and set to zero.  But that looks too complicated for me.  At this point I'm not sure how to proceed (and/or I have made a mistake, and if this is the even right approach).  Hopefully there is a simple argument I'm missing.  Maybe something to do with the denominators and not being able to cancel out if there is no gcd?

**UPDATE**

I have found the difference between two absolute terms in a given partial sum $S_n$ to be
$$ a_{k+1} - a_k = \Big( \frac{2k+3}{2k+1} \sqrt{\frac{n-k}{n+k+2}} - 1 \Big)a_k $$
A monotonically decreasing sequence will have
$$ a_{k+1} - a_k < 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \frac{2k+3}{2k+1} \sqrt{\frac{n-k}{n+k+2}} < 1. $$
With $k,n \geq 0$ in mind, this inequality [may be simplified](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282k%2B3%29%2F%282k%2B1%29%29%20sqrt%28%28n-k%29%2F%28n%2Bk%2B2%29%29%20%3C%201) to
$$ n \leq k^2 + 2k + \frac{1}{4}$$
and inverted to
$$ k \geq \sqrt{n + \frac{3}{4}} - 1.$$
This is saying that any fixed-$n$ partial sum $S_n$ will eventually reach its total via an alternating sum that absolutely decreases monotonically.  For example see [this plot for the n=60 case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlNNk.png); the blue line is the RHS of the above inequality.

And by flipping the above inequalities it's clear that the first $\approx \sqrt{n}$ elements are monotonically *increasing*.  So for a fixed $n$, the partial sum $S_n$ can be broken down: sum up the first $\approx \sqrt{n}$ elements and get some number.  The remaining $n - \sqrt{n}$ subsequent additions lead to a decreasingly small bobbing up and down around that number.

This feels like progress but it's not complete.

Comment: Side note: I would avoid thinking in phrases such as "$n<\infty$" and "before they reach infinity". Such phrases lead to the mental concept that infinity is something like "the biggest integer/real number", and that tends to lead to lots of pitfalls and errors in my experience.

Comment: Maybe someone can make the following idea work: let $p$ be the largest prime less than $2n+2$, so that $p\ge n+1$ by Bertrand's postulate. Then some of the summands contain a $\sqrt p$ in their denominators and others don't. One should be able to then solve for $\sqrt p$ as an expression containing only rational numbers and the square roots of the primes less than $p$; such an equality is impossible by standard algebraic number theory. I think the only pitfall is if some of the intermediate expressions vanished; maybe one can overcome this by generalizing the question and using induction.